# Overlapping table element left and right border

Tags: html, css, html-table, border, overlap

I want to set each element in the first row of my table to have a left border of a certain color and a right border of a certain color. Unfortunately, it looks like the borders of adjacent table cells are overlapping and I only get the left border color showing. The left border is supposed to be light gray and the right side dark gray.

[image]

Here is my HTML generating the table. (HTML is generated in cherrypy)

```
<th id="tbl_head" colspan='4'>%s</th>
    <tr>
        <td id="colhead">Track</td>
        <td id="colhead">Artist</td>
        <td id="colhead_time">Time</td>
        <td id="colhead">Album</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
table {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 3px;
}

#colhead {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #989898;
    color: #000000;

    border-left-color:   #aeaeae;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 2px;

    border-right-color: #6c6c6c;    
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;

}

#colhead_time {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #989898;
    color: #000000;

    border-left-color:   #aeaeae;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 2px;

    border-right-color: #6c6c6c;    
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;

}
```

Comment: Tried without `border-collapse`? Also, your `border-right-color` is not having valid values as pointed out in user2788058's answer below.

Comment: removing `border-collapse` and i can see both dark and light gray but I get an awful white line dividing up all of the cells in my table

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the below properties on your `table` CSS.

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0px;
```

```css
table {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
  padding: 3px;
}
#colhead {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #989898;
  color: #000000;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: blue;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
#colhead_time {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #989898;
  color: #000000;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: blue;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th id="tbl_head" colspan='4'>%s</th>
  <tr>
    <td id="colhead">Track</td>
    <td id="colhead">Artist</td>
    <td id="colhead_time">Time</td>
    <td id="colhead">Album</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/P9yD7/)

Comment: solved a td border issue in pdf. td border was getting larger than table width.
Thanks !

Comment: @varun: Welcome mate. Its nice to note that an old answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

In your css, you have added the wrong value for border-color property.
You write it as:

```
border-right-color: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
```

while it should be:

```
border-right-color: #6c6c6c;
```

Comment: Please add a ` both in front and end of the inline code blocks to format them as code. For multi-line codes, use the `{}` button in the button bar.

Answer (score 2):

It's your use of `border-collapse: collapse;` use `border-spacing:0;border-collapse:no-collapse;` instead.

Comment: There isn't a 'no-collapse' value for border-collapse. I think you ment 'separate' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse